# How to use query_string with date in elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, query-string

Does `query_string` support GT operation with date?

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "id"
    ]
  },
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "published": {
        "order": "DESC"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "updated > (2014-11-01T00:00:00Z)"
    }
  }
}
```

Throw `Failed to parse query [updated > (2014-11-01T00:00:00Z)]`

What is wrong with my query?

Mapping is:

```
"updated": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to be like this, i.e. in the [Lucene expression language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges)

```
  "query": "updated:{2014-11-01 TO *}"
```

However, you'd be better off using a simple `range` query:

```
"range": {
   "updated": {
      "gt": "2014-11-01T00:00:00Z"
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Val, are you sure about Lucene expression? Because my hits response is empty, but I am sure that thare is a valid document for this daterange.

Comment: Try without the time part, see my updated answer. If it doesn't work, please show a document that you think should match

Comment: It is same problem

Comment: please show a document that you think should match